# The element is getting properly inserted but it is printing one element less

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void insert(vector<int> &vec, int newEle)
{
    int i = vec.size() - 1;

    while (vec[i] > newEle)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
        vec[i + 1] = vec[i];
        i--;
    }
    vec[i + 1] = newEle;
}

void display(vector<int> &vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vect{4, 8, 13, 16, 20, 25, 28, 33};
    insert(vect, 18);
    display(vect);
    // cout << endl;
    // insert(vect, 11);
    // display(vect);
    return 0;
}
```

The element is getting properly inserted but it is printing one element less.

Output was this 4 8 13 16 18 20 25 28 with the 33 missing

Can anyone kindly help what to do? I am stuck

Comment: you should learn to use a debugger to walk through your code, your IDE probably has one, **use a debugger**.

Comment: `vec[i + 1] = vec[i];` does not add a new element. You should re-learn the chapter about vectors in your book. When you are a beginner, use the range checking `.at(i)`: `vec.at(i + 1) = vec.at(i);`

Comment: Side note : Change display implementation to `for (const auto value : vec) std::cout << value << " ";`. That is called a range based for loop and helps you to avoid mistakes with boundaries too

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You put a `rcpp` tag on this, but there is nothing about R and C++ and Rcpp glue here so I will edit the tag out.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration, `i` equals `vec.size() - 1`. You cannot then do `vec[i + 1] = vec[i]` because you are in essence accessing `vec[vec.size()]`, which is out of bounds, and therefore undefined behavior.

Besides that, in the second iteration, `i` equals `vec.size() - 2`. You are then doing `vec[i + 1] = vec[i]`, which is equivalent to `vec[vec.size() - 1] = vec[vec.size() - 2]`. You are discarding the last element of `vec` because you are overwriting it with the value of `vec[vec.size() - 2]`, so you are losing the last value.

More generally, `operator[]` doesn't change the size of the vector, so you are trying to insert a value without increasing the size of the vector to store the extra value. That doesn't work.

You can fix this using `vector::insert`:

```
while (vec[i] > newEle)
{
   cout << vec[i] << endl;
   i--;
}
vec.insert(vec.begin() + i + 1, newEle);
```

More about `vector::insert`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert